# Running python script (importing spacy) from Java using Runtime.exec

Tags: java, python, shell, spacy

I'm having this problem. I have a Python script doing some semantic similarity. This script include the import spacy sentence. This script have a method and two parameters. When I run this script in my terminal, everything goes well.

```
import spacy
import sys

# Create your models here.
class Clustering():
    nlp=None
    def __init__(self):
        self.nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_md")
                
    def process_text(self, text):
        ...
        return " ".join(result)
    
    def find_similarity(self, text1, text2):
        fixedText1 = self.process_text(text1)
        fixedText2 = self.process_text(text2)
        
        doc1 = self.nlp(fixedText1)
        doc2 = self.nlp(fixedText2)
        
        print(doc1.similarity(doc2))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    clus = Clustering('es', 'md')
    clus.find_similarity(sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])
```

This is how i run the script

```
python semanticsimilarity.py find_similarity 'El perro se salió del pozo' 'El banano se salió del pozo'
```

However, when I run it in Java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python semanticsimilarity.py find_similarity 'El perro se salió del pozo' 'El banano se salió del pozo'");
p.waitFor();
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "semanticsimilarity.py", line 9, in <module>
    import spacy
ImportError: No module named spacy
```

Is there any way to move around this? I think java is trying to run this inside the JVM or something, I dont know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python script depends on variables set up by your command line shell. The setup suggested by @PrasadU should work, or you could use `ProcessBuilder` class to the set same set of dependent variables for Python.

As your normal command line shell already has the setup, another approach is to simply launch your normal SHELL first and let that to launch your Python script - as that is exactly what you are really doing in your normal script launch.

So if you use Windows CMD.EXE or Linux BASH say, one of these may work as-is:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c \"python semanticsimilarity.py find_similarity 'El perro se salió del pozo' 'El banano se salió del pozo'\"");
```

OR

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("CMD.EXE /c \"python semanticsimilarity.py find_similarity 'El perro se salió del pozo' 'El banano se salió del pozo'\"");
```

Comment: Hi DuncG. I try using bin/bash but the problem remains: 
```String cmdArray[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "python semanticsimilarity.py find_similarity 'El perro se salió del pozo' 'El banano se salió del pozo' "};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);```
I'm going to try what PrasadU tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

most likely to do with ENV variables - `PATH , LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHONPATH`.   Set them for the original java start or use a shell script wrapper on python command to set them explicitly

grab the ENV values from terminal where the script works `echo PATH=$PATH ;   echo PYTHONPATH =$PYTHONPATH ;  echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH =$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ;`

---

Option-1 Set in your profile

```
export PATH=
export PYTHONPATH=
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
```

---

Option-2 Create a wrapper script
`wrapSymSim.sh`

```
export PATH=
export PYTHONPATH=
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=

python semanticsimilarity.py "$@"
```

call this in your java

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wrapSymSim.sh find_similarity 'El perro se salió del pozo' 'El banano se salió del pozo'");
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Hi PrasadU. It sounds interesting. However, I think I dont know how to do it, could you provide me with an url or example, please? Thank you.

Comment: Great! It works!!... but, now I have another problem, my python script is not taken the full string but the first two words of the first sentence. I run this: `./wrapper.sh find_similarity "El perro se salió del pozo" "El banano se salió del pozo"` And the exit is this: `'El perro 0.0 /Users/borisperezg/eclipsews/JythonTest/semanticsimilarity.py:50: UserWarning: [W008] Evaluating Doc.similarity based on empty vectors. print(doc1.similarity(doc2))` Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The script is taken `"El` and `perro` as the sentences to compare. I dont know why

Comment: can you share your `wrapper.sh` - its basically to do with quotes

Comment: Sure... 
`#! /bin/bash

export PATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

python /Users/borisperezg/eclipsews/JythonTest/semanticsimilarity.py $*`

Comment: change `$*` to `"$@"`.   `python /Users/borisperezg/eclipsews/JythonTest/semanticsimilarity.py "$@"`

Comment: Yep!, this works! Thank you @PrasadU for your cooperation, and thank you DuncG for your suggestion.